# Conditionally show and hide select input options that are generated from a database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

I have an html select input that shows book titles that are loaded from a database on page load. By default, I only want to show a book if it's publish date is within the last 6 months. Additionally,however, the user can select a checkbox to show all book titles regardless of publish date and Im confused on the best way to do this. I am getting the database information by making an ajax call to a handler method on page load. The handler method returns the title of the book as well as the publish date in an xml format. I then use jquery to find each book and append it as an option to my select statement. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the jquery statement I am using to append the database info as an option to my select input.

```js
if (status == "success" || status == "notmodified") {
  var strXml = $(response.responseXML);

  strXml.find('Book').each(function () {
    var value = $(this).attr('Name');
    var optionName = $(this).attr('Name');
    $('#ddlBookList').append('<option value="' + value + '">' + optionName + '</option>');
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using AJAX then there is no need to sort data on client if you do some time what happen client machine is not so good that can handle these kind of operation on page which lead to browser overload or even stop responding. so you should use a `AJAX` request to server which will execute a `SQL` since server is high end machine which can handle request like this easily in response which will return desired data.

but make sure not too many sorting should done on server side small can be done on client machine like sorting or hiding. When there are too many data display result is limited then you should use AJAX, when data is requested in sorted manner but sorting data already present on client not large data can be sorted on client side

Comment: I ended up making two separate functions that would make ajax calls to get the data. One ajax call would return filtered data, the other would return all data. I did the filtering in my sql statement. Thank you for your recommendations.